# Configure Homestead for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, phpstorm, homestead

I am trying to configure a Homestead environment for a Laravel server, but I can't get it to work. I followed the documentation to install and configure Homestead and Vagrant. This is my `Homestead.yaml`

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\\Users\\meadi\\PhpstormProjects
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: blog.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/blog/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

Where PhpstormProjects is the folder with all my php projects, and `blog` is the folder of the project that I am trying to make the set up for. Running `vagrant up` in the project root resulted in this `Vagrantfile` (used the Vagrant tool in PhpStorm so I assume this is a template provided by PhpStorm):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Ansible, Chef, Docker, Puppet and Salt are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

I see that most of the file is commented out, but I don't know if I should enable any of this configurations. After running `vagrant provision` I expected to be able to connect to the server in a browser. I set up `hosts` mapping from  192.168.10.10 to blog.test, and I also tried connecting straight to 192.168.10.10 and localhost:8000, but with no success, Chrome telling me the site can't be reached.

Browsing the remote in PhpStorm shows me this folder structure: [image: Vagrant brows remote]

I see that there is no '/home/vagrant/code' directory, even though that is the mapping in `Homestead.yaml`, and when running `vagrant up` I get this printed in the console:

```
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/meadi/PhpstormProjects/blog
```

I assume that I misconfigured something that resulted in the code folder not being mounted in the VM thus resulting in no `public` folder to be served.  Can anyone help me out? I followed multiple tutorials and I can't seem to find out what I missed. Thanks in advance!

Also, here is my Remote configuration in PhpStorm. I assume that if I misconfigured that, the folder structure I see in the Remote won't be accurate.

[image: PhpStorm remote]
[image: PhpStorm remote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may hide in this part of your Homestead.yaml:

```
folders:
- map: C:\\Users\\meadi\\PhpstormProjects
  to: /home/vagrant/code
```

At first, you don't have to use double backslashes in your path, you're enough to write like this:

```
C:\Users\meadi\PhpstormProjects
```

Second, your project folder is mapped to **/home/vagrant/code**, but you want to set your project in "blog" folder, so you need to change your mapping like this:

```
/home/vagrant/code/blog
```

Also, you should put your concrete blog project in "blog" directory on your host machine:

```
C:\Users\meadi\PhpstormProjects\blog
```

And define this path in your Homestead.yaml

The final variant is:

```
folders:
- map: C:\Users\meadi\PhpstormProjects\blog
  to: /home/vagrant/code/blog
```

If you want to create another project (e.g., shop), you must add another mapping:

```
folders:
- map: C:\Users\meadi\PhpstormProjects\blog
  to: /home/vagrant/code/blog
- map: C:\Users\meadi\PhpstormProjects\shop
  to: /home/vagrant/code/shop
```

**EDIT**

Check, if you have followed all these installation steps:

1. After installation vagrant and virtualbox, run *vagrant box add laravel/homestead* from any location in your cmd
2. Go to **empty** folder for your projects and run *git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead*
3. After cloning this package, run *init.bat* script inside it
4. It will generate Homestead.yaml **that you need to edit**
5. *vagrant up* from the folder where your Homestead.yaml locates

Comment: Made the change but still no result. After destorying and recreating the vm, there is still no code folder in the remote, and sure enough nothing pops up on '127.0.0.1:8000', '192.168.10.10' or 'blog.test'

Comment: @Adrian, try to run "vagrant up" from cmd or Powershell and then run vagrant ssh to connect the remote, don't use Phpstorm now. Then check the folders with ls -a command. Homestead.yaml seems to be configured correctly, so you should see code/blog path.

Comment: Same result. Also destroyed the previous vm and re-run `vagrant init` from powershell instead of Phpstorm, but still no code folder (checked directly with ssh)

Comment: @Adrian, hey, you don't have to run vagrant init. I'll update the answer, check if you did all the steps I describe

Comment: Oh, so i have to run vagrant up from the homestead folder. I see that now it doesn't generate the ssh keys automatically.Where does '~/.ssh/id_rsa' resolve to? (i am not sure what ~/ means on windows'

Comment: Nevermind, I saw that was default path fro `ssh-keygen`. Thank you very much!